# Office 365 security & compliance and Microsoft 365 compliance

Tags: compliance-center

I am a bit confused in terms of creating a retention policy and creating a label. There are two locations where you can create labels and policies:

1. https://compliance.microsoft.com
2. https://protection.office.com/

Can someone please explain the difference between these two locations? I am trying to create a retention policy and label for the SharePoint environment.

Kind Regards